# Accommodate object specific Stored Procedures in a Generic DAO

Tags: java, jdbc, dao, abstract-factory

I am working on a Servlet-JSP-JDBC application. NO Spring/Hibernate -  Pure JDBC. As a best practice I have implemented an Abstract Factory DAO class and am using domain-object specific DAO interfaces. Here is example :

```
public abstract class DAOFactory {
     public abstract ContactDAO getContactDAO();
     public abstract UserDAO getUserDAO();
     ...
}

public interface ContactDAO {
   public int insertContact();
   public Contact findContact(String ContactId );
   ...
}

public interface UserDAO {
   public int insertUser();
   public User findUser(String UserId );
   ...
}

public class MySQLContactDAO implements ContactDAO {...}

public class MySQLUserDAO implements UserDAO {...}

public class Contact {}  // contactbean

public class User {}  // userbean
```

As you can see, all the methods in all the interface are similar. ( i could have defined a generic DAO interface I know, but i dropped that idea for simplicity )

But in my User table i have added a stored procedure which is a sort of user authentication helper method. I'd call a wrapper method at Login page.

```
   boolean isValidUser (String uname, String pwd){
       // call to stored procedure here 
   }
```

As of now only the User table has a stored procedure like this. Given that all the DAO interfaces should have same / similar methods, how can I accommodate the method which calls this Stored Procedure in the UserDAO interface ?

**I have thought two options :**

1. Simply add the isValidUser() method to only UserDAO interface and implement in the concrete class.
2. Add the isValidUser() method to the User ( userbean ) class

**My question is :** Are the above two options valid from the "design/implementation/maintenance" perspective ? If yes which one is the better ?

If you can suggest some alternatives I'd be really grateful !

Thanks in advance !

Comment: @Satya : thanks for the edits !

Comment: I realized it myself that option # 2 is not going to be elegant as it will put JDBC code inside the userbean object !